# Avoid global object pollution inside third-party AMD module

Tags: requirejs, javascript, amd, js-amd

I have third-party modules, loaded with requirejs. Every module, in its definition, calls require to load some library (local to the module) that it needs.

```
// SAMPLE MODULE
define(['require'], function(require) {

    function init (args) {
        require ([./somelibrary], function { /* ... */ });
    }

    return (initFunc: init);
 }
```

The module perfectly works on its own. But if I try to load multiple modules, they can load different version of the same non-amd library. Let's make an example:

If `somelibrary` sets a global name in the window object, like in `window.somelibrary = some_library_code`. If module1 loads somelibrary0.1 and module2 loads somelibrary0.2 shortly after, module1 ends using somelibrary0.2, which is not good.

Considering that I can't change how the modules work, is there a method to "trick" require to have a different window object created by me? Like this:

```
require ([module1, module2], function (mod_1, mod_2) {

    // LOAD MODULE 1
    var fakeWindow1 = {}
    /* do the magic */
    mod_1.init ();
    /* somelibrary required by module1 ends up in fakeWindow1.somelibrary */

    // LOAD MODULE 2
    var fakeWindow2 = {}
    /* do the magic */
    mod_2.init ();
    /* somelibrary required by module2 ends up in fakeWindow2.somelibrary */
}
```

If that's not possible, what can I do to avoid global context pollution?

Please notice I **can not** change the modules' code.

Comment: hey, start a bounty! I wanna know this too